# Set up an SQL Queries where row content is in columns

Tags: mysql

I have a payment table that has a time column, payment provider column, and a revenue column.

I want to get my results in the following format:

Date Payment Provider Total Payment Provider #2 Total ....

Here is the query:

```
select date(from_unixtime(payment_notification_norm_created)) as 'Date',
  payment_notification_norm_provider as 'Payment_Provider',
  sum(payment_notification_norm_revenue) as 'Total Revenue'
from payment_notification_norm
  where payment_notification_norm_created>'1391212800'
  and payment_notification_norm_event='Payment received'
group by Date,Payment_Provider;
```

I would like to see one row for each date, with each payment provider as a column with its revenue sum as the entry in the respective row.

Thanks.

Comment: And is failing where??

Comment: Date is a bad name for an expression, as it is also a key word. So group by _Date_ may be your problem. Rename it to Payment_Date and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of query is, generally, known as a *pivot* in which rows of a table or result set are pivoted to columns.  This is a little difficult to do in a general way in MySQL.

You are, it seems, also aggregating by date.

But here is a possible specific way to do something like what you need.

```
SELECT DATE(payment_notification_norm_created) as 'Date',
       SUM(IF(payment_notification_norm_provider='Provider 1',
              payment_notification_norm_revenue,0)) AS `Provider_1`,
       SUM(IF(payment_notification_norm_provider='Provider 2',
              payment_notification_norm_revenue,0)) AS `Provider_2`,
       SUM(IF(payment_notification_norm_provider='Provider 3',
              payment_notification_norm_revenue,0)) AS `Provider_3`,
       SUM(payment_notification_norm_revenue) as 'Total Revenue'
  FROM payment_notification_norm
 WHERE payment_notification_norm_created >= DATE('2014-02-01')
   AND payment_notification_norm_event = 'Payment received'
 GROUP BY DATE(payment_notification_norm_created)
```

Notice a couple of things about this.

First, you are correct that you're summarizing by both date and provider.  But you need to do the provider summary using conditional sums to get the pivot to work.

Second, I took advantage of the fact that MySQL automatically conforms *nix-style TIMESTAMP values to DATETIME values, to shorten some of your date arithmetic and make it more obvious. You may need to do something else.

Third, you had `>` in your sample query. That's usually wrong, and should usually be replaced by `>=` for the beginning of a time range. You want all the payments that happened *on or after* midnight on Feb 1, 2014, not just those that happened *after* that moment in time.    Now, of course, your billing department are probably asleep at midnight. But what if somebody comes in next month and posts a bunch of correction payments exactly at midnight?

Finally, these pivot operations are such a pain in the neck in pure SQL that many people choose to do them using some kind of host language or reporting package instead.